# Unexpected T_VARIABLE when parsing XML Element with php variable

Tags: php, xml

I have a flat XML file that contains User_ID_1_, User_ID_2_, etc.  I am trying to do a while loop that shows each of these fields.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_file);
$line=1;
while ($line<5){
echo "<h3>Line ".$line."</h3>".$xml->Display_Name_$line_;
$line++;
}
```

But this does not work and i get:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$line_' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'`
Which makes sense because $line_ is not what I'm looking for; $line is what I need.

Yes, the extra underscore is required (blame Cisco for any poor XML practices).  How can I use a PHP variable as part of the XML node lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a curly brace and quotes to the property:

```
echo "<h3>Line ". $line. "</h3>" . $xml->{"Display_Name_$line_"};
```

This topic can be found in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Thanks.  I did have to concatenate out the `$line` variable but that fixed it

Comment: @macaddict89 yes that way would work too, in the answer above, `$line` will also be interpolated inside the double quotes too, yielding `Display_Name_1_` and so forth. glad this helped